# MKAnnotationView resizing and scaling

Tags: swift, mapkit

I want to apply scaleAspectFill and control the resolution of the view, but MKAnnotationView only allows direct manipulation of the UIImage and not the UIImageView. Is there any way to set properties of the annotation view?

Comment: You probably would need to create a custom MKAnnotationView and implement your own ImageView

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074620/swift-custom-mkannotationview-set-label-title