# Trying to do custom callout and change Marker color in Swift MapView

Tags: swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I am very new to Swift and Xcode so please be kind and make no assumptions if you can answer my question :-).

I would like to have a custom annotation on a map which uses a custom icon AND a custom callout view.

I found code which will do the custom callout ([Swift - Custom MKAnnotationView, set label title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074620/swift-custom-mkannotationview-set-label-title/65815159#65815159)) however that does not allow my custom icon to work.

Here is my code

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    
    // myCustomAnnotation allows me to send private data so I can change things like marker color
    guard let annotation = annotation as? myCustomAnnotation
     
     else {
            
            return nil
        }
    
    /* This is the code for doing the "Hello World" callout
    var customCallout = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "MyMarker")
    if customCallout == nil
    {
        customCallout = CustomAnnotationView.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "MyMarker")
        customCallout?.setSelected(true, animated: true)
    }
    // End of code for custom callout

    // Start of code for changing Marker color and custom image for marker
    let annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "MyMarker")
    
    annotationView.markerTintColor = UIColor.yellow
    
    let annotationColor: String = annotation.annotationColor!

    annotationView.glyphImage = UIImage(named: "myCustomImage")
    // End of code for changing color of marker and changing image of marker

    // If I return annotationView then the pin color changes and the custom icon for the pin shows but the "Hello World" box does not show
    //return annotationView
    
    // This will cause the "Hello World" to show but the default pin icon and color is used
    // Looking for a way to do both
    return customCallout
}

// Code for custom Marker
class CustomAnnotationView : MKPinAnnotationView
{
    let selectedLabel:UILabel = UILabel.init(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 140, height: 38))

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
    {
        super.setSelected(false, animated: animated)

        if(selected)
        {
            
            // Do customization, for example:
            selectedLabel.text = "Hello World!!"
            selectedLabel.textAlignment = .center
            selectedLabel.font = UIFont.init(name: "HelveticaBold", size: 15)
            selectedLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            selectedLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
            selectedLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2
            selectedLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            selectedLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true

            selectedLabel.center.x = 0.5 * self.frame.size.width;
            selectedLabel.center.y = -0.5 * selectedLabel.frame.height;
            self.addSubview(selectedLabel)
        }
        else
        {
            selectedLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't subclass `MKMarkerAnnotationView` in your custom code? Are you aware that your custom class `CustomAnnotationView` is not used because of `let annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView...`? Are you aware that you can customise standard callouts so you don't have to write them yourself? (I admit I wrote my own callouts but this is NOT a beginners topic, for many use cases you don't have to do this).

Comment: You might work through this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/7738344-mapkit-tutorial-getting-started