# MKAnnotationView does not show title when using custom image

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mkannotationview

I've followed the guidelines from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/ios-maps/ios-maps-walkthrough) to display custom annotations on a map.

However, I'm just able to customise the image with the price of loosing the annotation title. In the following code, taken from MapDelegate's [GetViewForAnnotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/mapkit.mkmapviewdelegate.getviewforannotation?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12), the custom image is not set just to confirm that the title will be shown.

```
MapKit.MKAnnotationView vehicleView = (MapKit.MKAnnotationView)mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation(mKPointAnnotation.Subtitle.GetHashCode().ToString());
if (vehicleView == null)
{
    vehicleView = new MapKit.MKAnnotationView(annotation, mKPointAnnotation.Subtitle.GetHashCode().ToString());

    byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(mKPointAnnotation.Subtitle);
    NSData data = NSData.FromArray(encodedDataAsBytes);
    var uiImage = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);

    vehicleView.CanShowCallout = true;

    //vehicleView.Image = uiImage;

    vehicleView.Layer.ZPosition = 7;

}

return vehicleView;
```

Let's see the results:

Without custom image, we have the title.

[image]

With the custom image I'm loosing the title.

[image]

What can I do about that?

Comment: When you select the AnnotationView,could it display the title ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Yes, but I want it to be displayed all the time.

Comment: You could try to custom the MKPinAnnotationView and do whatever customization you want there.Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/34701210/10768653.